# MRTK 2.4 - Reattach Hand Menu

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

I used the prefab [HandMenu_Large_WorldLock_On_GrabAndPull](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_HandMenu.html) as a basis for my hand menu. If grabbing the menu and placing it somewhere, I stays there and this behavior is fine for me. But now I want to walk away, looking again at my hand and the menu should reattach to my hand. How to set up `HandConstraintPalmUp` to achieve that?

**What I tried:**
I read [here](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_HandMenu.html) that I could set the `SolverHandler` to true or call the method `HandConstraintPalmUp.StartWorldLockReattachCheckCoroutine()` but this is actually not setting the `SolverHandler` to true, it just stays false. If running it via Holographic Emulation and setting the handler to true by clicking in the editor, it works, but not via `OnFirstHandDetected` or `OnHandActivate` of `HandConstraintPamlUp`. Also the documentation says:
 *When trying to set the hand constrained object to start following your hand again (based on whether it meets the activation criteria), set the SolverHandler's UpdateSolver to true.*
But what is the criteria for the solver to set `UpdateSolvers` to true? What am I missing here?
Menu with default settings:

 Why is for example the `OnClick`-Event on the button `BtnClose` working and my call on `OnHandActiavte` not?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, since the `Use Gaze Activation` checkbox of `HandConstraintPalmUp` component is disabled by default, and the coroutine function `WorldLockedReattachCheck()` invoked by `StartWorldLockReattachCheckCoroutine()` method has a conditional statement will evaluate the `useGazeActivation` property to decide whether to execute the statements following. If you did not enable the `Use Gaze Activation`, it will never update the `UpdateSolver` property to true.  You can refer to the source code of this class for details: [HandConstraintPalmUp.cs Line 392](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/e21bdec34e715d675f7929711b5bcee05747844f/Assets/MRTK/SDK/Features/Utilities/Solvers/HandConstraintPalmUp.cs#L392). To fix it, you can enable the `Use Gaze Activation` for your project or update the value of `SolverHandler.UpdateSolvers` directly in your code.

Besides, the `OnHandActiavte` event is always work fine for me, I can't reproduce your issue on my machine. Could you provide more information about it? And if you have question about how to use it, you can find examples in the `HandMenuLayoutExamples` scene under Assets/MRTK/Examples/Experimental/HandMenuLayout/Scenes.

Comment: `OnHandActivate` by itself works. All I had to do is enabling `UseGazeActivation`. Thanks! Didn't pay attention to this checkbox, because did not want to add this constraint.